# How to over come ssh error: cannot open display: localhost:11.0

Tags: ssh, firefox

Hoping someone can help. I have been searching the web put failed find a solution that has helped.
I have recently updated my Ubuntu VM from version 20.04 to version 22.04. After the update was complete, I am no longer able to use winxserver to open a browser of the server on my local laptop screen. Luckly, I have a VMWare snapshot and can easily jump between the 2 version of the server. Ubuntu 20.04 works using the below steps, but 22.04 will not.

I have followed some hints found online:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config -> X11Forwarding yes
echo $DISPLAY -> localhost:11.0
cat /etc/hosts -> 127.0.0.1 localhost
                  127.0.1.1 server_name
```

I have tried deleting my .Xauthority file in the home directory of the user I am ssh'ing as, and letting it recreate at next log, but error persists.
confirmed x11-apps is at latest version

```
sudo apt install x11-apps
x11-apps is already the newest version (7.7+8build2).
```

Steps taken to reproduce:

- On Windows 11 laptop installed cygwin with Xserver
- Open cygwin, at
  the prompt start the Xserver with command `startxwin -- -listen tcp`
- Open a 2nd window in cygwin
- On the 2nd terminal screen set the
  display variable -> `export DISPLAY=11.0`
- Attempt to ssh -> `ssh -Y -C user@IP firefox`
- Get prompt for password. After entering my password get error:

  ```
  Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: 11.0
  Error: Can't open display: localhost:13.0
  ```
- I then change my cygwin display to be 13.0 by using command '$ export DISPLAY=13.0'
  then get error.

  Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
  Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: 13.0
  Error: Can't open display: localhost:14.0
- For interest if I just use PuTTy and ssh to the server as the same user. Attempt to open firefox in the background from the command prompt, using command `firefox &` I get error:

`server_name:~$ MoTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol Error: cannot open display: localhost:11.0`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Hi Jos I gave your suggestion a try still getting error. When starting the Xserver in cygwin I see it exports the display as 0:0 -> winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0. I have exported my display like you suggested: $ export DISPLAY=:0 Make ssh connection $ ssh -Y -C user@IP user@IP's password: Make connection to Ubuntu Server Attempt to start firefox kw@kpmg-apicup:~$ firefox & [1] 21635 user@server_name:~$ X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication. Error: cannot open display: localhost:12.0

I seem to have found a solution by continuing to search on google. Incase anyone else gets this issue in the future here is what I did.

1. Open cygwin session on windows 11 laptop
2. From there start the xserver running command
   #startxwin -- -listen tcp
3. check what display cygwin exports, in my case it was 0:0
4. Open a new window on the cygwin and export Display
   #export DISPLAY=0.0
5. On a ssh connection to the Ubuntu VM I then typed the below command
   to start firefox, should be done as the user you want to connect as
   #XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority /snap/bin/firefox  (found this on
   google)
6. A couple of seconds later my firefox browser from the VM appears on
   my laptop screen.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution by continuing to search on google. Incase anyone else gets this issue in the future here is what I did.

1. Open cygwin session on windows 11 laptop
2. From there start the xserver running command `# startxwin -- -listen tcp`
3. check what display cygwin exports, in my case it was 0:0
4. Open a new window on the cygwin and export Display `# export DISPLAY=0.0`
5. On a ssh connection to the Ubuntu VM I then typed the below command to start firefox, should be done as the user you want to connect as `# XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority /snap/bin/firefox` (found this on google)
6. A couple of seconds later my firefox browser from the VM appears on my laptop screen.